# How to dive into stacked dict gracefully

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dict like

```
{
    "key_a": "value",
    "key_b": {
        "key_b_a": "value",
        "key_b_b": {
            "key_b_b_a": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to create a method to delete the given key or change its value.

```
def del_key(key):
    my_dict = <dictionary described above>
    keys = key.split(':')
    if len(keys) == 1:
        del my_dict[keys[0]]
    elif len(keys) == 2:
        del my_dict[keys[0]][keys[1]]
    elif len(keys) == 3:
        del my_dict[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]]
    . . .

del_key('key_b:key_b_b:key_b_b_a')
del_key('key_b:key_b_b')
del_key('key_a')
```

How can I do this gracefully?

Comment: What's wrong with the current 'del' command? Seems like it already does what your method does just with slightly different syntax.

Comment: dictionary structure may differ and it may have any number stacked dictionaries. if-else is a rather ugly solution to delete a key in, say, 10th sublevel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It assumes your input is valid key,otherwise you have to check.

```
data = {
    "key_a": "value",
    "key_b": {
        "key_b_a": "value",
        "key_b_b": {
            "key_b_b_a": "value"
        }
    }
}

def del_key(key):
    key = key.split(':')
    temp = data
    for i in key[:-1]:
        temp = temp[i]
    del temp[key[-1]]
    return data

print del_key('key_b:key_b_b:key_b_b_a')
print del_key('key_b:key_b_b')
print del_key('key_a')

output:
{'key_a': 'value', 'key_b': {'key_b_a': 'value', 'key_b_b': {}}}
{'key_a': 'value', 'key_b': {'key_b_a': 'value'}}
{'key_b': {'key_b_a': 'value'}}
```

Comment: @AlexanderZhak :) not a problem

Comment: With `data` as a function parameter and checking existence of the keys this would be a wonderful answer :) (currently is also good, but there is always something to tweak :P)

Comment: @ImanolLuengo  agree. key validation should improve the code.